# PHP: filter my input fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can i filter my input fields.. such as incoming $_POST, $_GETs etc..

I am using prepared statements with PDO, so i just transfer the $_POST directly to the PDO(not doing mysql_real_escape_string) anymore.

But example i transfer a $_POST var in to a $_SESSION and right now i do it directly, but shouldnt i filter it somehow? PDO is just for the database, what about in "general"?

Comment: to broad, it will depend what the var is going to be used for if and how you them 'filter' it

Comment: what is the session data going to be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You should also do sanity checks on the data.

So if you are inserting an integer, check it with `is_numeric()` first.

If you expect an email address, make sure it matches an email regexp.

You should always do checks like this on data you are inserting to the database.

Once the data has been vetted for inserting into the db, you can use in session safely.

This will help prevent XSS attacks, and keep your data clean.

Comment: How does checking a variable's type with `is_numeric` going to prevent XSS attacks?

Comment: because `<script>do some bad stuff</script>` will fail. as will rogue image tags etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i have $_SESSION['attach'] = $_POST['image']; and I am going to use the $_SESSION['attach'] later to display a image(<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION..; ?>") how should i sanitize

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this. Not perfect but it's good.

```
  function clear($data)
    {

        $data = addslashes($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        $bir = array('/\//', '/\^/', '/\./', '/\$/', '/\|/', '/\(/', '/\)/', '/\[/', '/\]/',
            '/\*/', '/\+/', '/\?/', '/\{/', '/\}/', '/\,/');
        $iki = array('\/', '\^', '\.', '\$', '\|', '\(', '\)', '\[', '\]', '\*', '\+', '\?',
            '\{', '\}', '\,');
        $data = preg_replace($bir, $iki, $data);
        return $data;

    }

// USAGE
clear($_GET[]) or clear($_POST[])
```

Alsı, you have to check variables with is_numeric , is_boolen, is_string functions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you filter any output from `$_SESSION` you don't need to filter it before setting. A good way to remember to filter is with a simple `raw_` naming convention:

```
$_SESSION['raw_val'] = $_POST['val'];
```

That way you've got the value stored for later, when you may want to filter the value in a different manner:

```
$_SESSION['filter1_val'] = applyFilter1($_SESSION['raw_val']);
$_SESSION['filter2_val'] = applyFilter2($_SESSION['raw_val']);
```

Of course it may be a good idea to validate the *size* of `$_POST['val']` so that you're not storing large volumes of data in your session vars.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give inputs like

> ' " '

If your code breaks yu know that your input needs to be filtered.

By regular expression filetering for alphabets and numerics can also help you.

Every forums or articles says that prepared statement are free from sql injection.

But  i think if you are not making the prepared statement properly it will break.

If you are using SP , test that too.